# Dynamic colour change on scroll with jQuery

Tags: jquery, advanced-custom-fields

I have a div which changes colour when I scroll down the page, from transparent to opaque. This code currently is using static RGB values and then adds an opacity value based on the scroll position.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var $scrollPercent = ($(document).scrollTop() / windowHeight);

        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $(".fade-overlay").css({backgroundColor:'rgba(0,168,80,'+$scrollPercent+')'});
        } else {
            $(".fade-overlay").css({backgroundColor:'rgba(0,168,80,'+$scrollPercent+')'});
        }
    });
});
```

I want to change the static RGB values to dynamic ones.

At present I do have a hexadecimal colour value created by Advanced Custom Fields in a field called 'primary_colour'.
I can output this value as 'background-color' to a div but wonder if it is possible to convert this to RGB and insert it into the code I already have?

Can anyone possibly help me with my quandary about how to get this to work? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $(".fade-overlay").css({backgroundColor:'rgba(0,168,80,'+$scrollPercent+')'});
} else {
    $(".fade-overlay").css({backgroundColor:'rgba(0,168,80,'+$scrollPercent+')'});
}
```

change all occurrences of `backgroundColor` to `"background-color"` or declare a variable first!